# Rails console not working on server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ssh, rails-console

When I run `bundle exec rails console production` or `rails console production` via SSH on the server in the `Current` folder of the Capistrano deploy I get:

```
Usage:
     rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
    (...)
```

with an explanation to start a new app. Locally it works. Why can't I start a console remotely?

Comment: Does this work? `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console`

Comment: @Eugene I get the same message as above. No idea why, rails and ruby are installed.

Comment: Did you load your environment? rvm gemset or rbenv or else

Comment: I started the (thin) server which is running. How can I load the environment? `rvm gemset` gives `Unknown subcommand ' '`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I'm assuming that you updated to `rails 4` from version 3 and your app can't find the executables in the `bin` directory. Run this to see your rails version:

```
$ rails -v
```

If your `rails` version is 4 or above, try running this:

```
$ rake rails:update:bin
```

---

Source: [Rails 4 Release Notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#railties-notable-changes)

> #### 6.1  Notable changes
>
> - Your app's executables now live in the `bin/` dir. Run `rake rails:update:bin` to get `bin/bundle`, `bin/rails`, and `bin/rake`.

Comment: I did not update Rails. It is a clean install. I will try to run the command anyway.

Comment: "bundle exec rake rails:update:bin" worked for me and then "bundle exec rails c"

Comment: I tried this solution but got the follwoing error: "No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)". I am new to ruby and rake. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I had to slightly alter the command to `bundle exec rake app:update:bin`.

Answer (score 21):

I am using capistrano to deploy, including the capistrano/bundler gem.  Since the ./`bin` directory is version controlled in Rails 4, we need to prevent Capistrano from linking it on deployments by removing bin from `set :linked_dirs`.

Now in order to prevent bundler from overwriting the version controlled binstubs, we can add the line `set :bundle_binstubs, nil` which will prevent capistrano-bundler from setting the --binstubs option when running bundle install.

My config/deploy.rb file now has these lines:

```
# Default value for linked_dirs is []
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')

set :bundle_binstubs, nil
```

Note the lack of the `bin` directory in the `:linked_dirs` line.

Answer (score 15):

I have the same problem, and turns out when you deploy through cap `shared/bin` is symlink to `current/bin`.

Here's what works for me:

- `rm current/bin`
- `mkdir current/bin`
- `rake rails:update:bin`

This should help, but it is somewhat a temporary solution, I'm trying to find out how to make cap not auto symlink-ing current/bin.

Answer (score 9):

In case of **Rails 5.2**

I had to remove bin directory by running below command in project root directory.

```
 rm -rf bin
```

and then I ran another command in project root directory:

```
 rake app:update:bin
```

It will show you output like below:

```
  create  bin
  create  bin/bundle
  create  bin/rails
  create  bin/rake
  create  bin/setup
  create  bin/update
  create  bin/yarn
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a little while since this was answered.

In my case I needed to run:

```
rake app:update:bin
```

Note- app rather than rails.

I was missing the bin directory all-together in my Rails 5.1 App

Comment: Yes, had success with `bundle exec rake app:update:bin`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue on my production server when I updated my application from Rails 5.2 to 6.0.4. Simply follow these steps:

```
cd to_your_project_dir
rm -r bin
rake app:update:bin
```