# rails c wont work in app directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, ubuntu-16.04, rbenv

Im trying to reach the production env console. I think rbenv is messing with me.

When i run `rails console production` i get the old:

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]
```

So i figure, it doesn't recognize my dir as an rails app because of the versions so I run. So the rails -v tells me:

```
deploy@webb-labb2:~/prognoser/current$ rails -v
Rails 5.1.0
```

Which is the wrong version of the app. 
And the bundle exec rails -v command gives me:

```
deploy@webb-labb2:~/prognoser/current$ bundle exec rails -v
Rails 4.2.8
```

Which is the correct version. But the:

```
deploy@webb-labb2:~/prognoser/current$ bundle exec rails console production
```

Still gives me the old:

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]
```

Comment: have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25713712/4614833

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails console not working on server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25711146/rails-console-not-working-on-server)

Comment: So that was related to the problem. Allthough I had run the command under bundle. Not bundle exec. So therefore it generated binstubs for the wrong railsversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran

```
$ bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
```

that did the trick. And I had to add a boot file to the shared/config directory.